# Logo only on the first pages

Tags: logos

Currently I have a logo on the bottom right on all my pages.

I only want to have it on the first pages, i.e. table of contents list of figures and so. When the text starts I do not want to have the logo anymore. I added the picture with `addtoshipoutpicture` My code is:

I commented out the the chapters.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,   
            12pt,                               
            bibliography=totoc,     
            index=totoc,    
            abstracton,     
            headsepline,    
            ]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage{latexsym}             
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
    \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}   
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,lipsum}
    \usepackage{tocstyle}
    \usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
    \usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{calligra}




\setlength{\footskip}{10mm} 
\begin{document}                    



\newpage

\clearpage

\AddToShipoutPicture{
\hspace{14cm}
 {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{logosblack.jpg}}}

\newpage

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
\vspace{-10cm}{\fontfamily{calligra}\selectfont \begin{huge} \hspace{2cm}To my parents and siblings. \end{huge}}
\end{minipage}


\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}


%\input{Chapter1} 
%\input{Chapter2}
%\newpage
%\input{Chapter3}
%\newpage
%\input{Appendix}
\newpage

% no logos here !!!!!!
Text text .....
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `\ClearShipoutPicture` before the page where you don't want the logo starts.

Note that `\AddToShipoutPicture*` (starred version) can be used to show the logo in a single page.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,   
            12pt,                               
            bibliography=totoc,     
            index=totoc,    
            abstracton,     
            headsepline,    
            ]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage{latexsym}             
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
    \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}   
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,lipsum}
    \usepackage{tocstyle}
    \usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
    \usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{calligra}




\setlength{\footskip}{10mm} 
\begin{document}                    



\newpage

\clearpage

\AddToShipoutPicture{
\hspace{14cm}
 {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{logosblack.jpg}}}

\newpage

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
\vspace{-10cm}{\fontfamily{calligra}\selectfont \begin{huge} \hspace{2cm}To my parents and siblings. \end{huge}}
\end{minipage}


\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}


%\input{Chapter1} 
%\input{Chapter2}
%\newpage
%\input{Chapter3}
%\newpage
%\input{Appendix}
\newpage

% no logos here !!!!!!
\ClearShipoutPicture % From here on no logo
Text text .....
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `\AddToShipoutPicture*` instead of `\AddToShipoutPicture`.

Comment: Where should I insert it? @Uwe Ziegenhagen Should I just add \AddToShipoutPicture* where the text is?

Comment: On the page where you want the element.

Comment: The difference between starred/unstarred versions of the [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) macros is given on the *first* page of the [`eso-pic` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic/eso-pic.pdf) (section **2.1 Basic commands for adding LaTeX stuff to the page background**).